# XIAO Seeed seens with PN532 transfer data with BLE

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, nfc-p2p, nrf52

I m new to programing can you help me with a code for send/recive nfc data from a phone to an XIAO Seeed seens to PN532 shield and revers to show data in phone like an POS.

Thanks for help me.

I tried to make a code but i have so many errors, exactly what i said. I new with this can you hel me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you want to tranfer data via NFC or BLE? Your title does not match the rest